# Set background behind image

Tags: android, background, imageview

I got a picture that I want to use. 
I set it as following:

```
ImageView menu = new ImageView(this);

menu.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

  menu.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu);
```

They annoying thing is that I get white pixels on the sides of it cause I want to keep the aspect of the pic.

I can stretch the image by using `menu.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);` but that will make the person on it look really fat. The picture is dark and the pixels are white so they do show quite well. :/

Is there I way I can first apply black color and then the image above that color?

Comment: sure setBackgroundColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a background color to any view on android you can use `android:background` attribute in layout xml or by calling `setBackgroundColor(int id)` in java code.

But if you really want just to set the image in bounds you can give a try to `android:scaletype="centerCrop"`

Answer (score 0):

Using set BackgroundColor will also remove any padding, borders and what not attached to the object.
If that is the result you want, that is a reasonable approach.
If blasting the objects current style will cause problems, I would look to use CSS to set the background color and change the css styles through code if things are happening after page load.
Consider using a border around the image that is colored the way you want to hide what is underneath?